# Read file from conten path

Tags: android

I am useing file chooser to choose a simple text file, however problem is that it returns path in 
`content:/com.android.externalrnalstorage.documents/document/1BF4-1E18%3Astudents.txt` 
(students.txt is located at sdcard).

I tried all getpath() functions available everywhere on net, but they dont work for me. They either give me `/document/1BF4-1E18:students.txt`
 or the one with kitkat compatiblity gives me `content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1BF4-1E18%3Astudents.txt`.
I have really tried, so is there any way I can read file using `content:/com....` without any conversions?

**Thanks to CommonsWare**, I got it working, Here is the snippet.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
InputStream in = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have really tried, so is there any way I can read file using content:/com.... without any conversions?

I do not know what "without any conversions" means here. To read in the content from a `content://` `Uri`, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.